# Calculations on grouped rows using lambda functions in c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to calculate Best and Worst body measurement changes for people who go on a fitness trip.

I have a database full of before and after body composition measurements for several people who go on various trips.  Every participant and every trip has an Id.  There are 3 types of readings, B(efore), M(iddle) and A(fter).  Here is an example of the data:

```
ParticipantId TripId Type  Weight   BodyFatPct
1               2     B    195      22.8
1               2     B    189.6    24.1
1               2     A    186.6    21.2
1               2     A    187.6    23.8
2               3     B    199.2    23.7
2               3     B    198.4    25.1
2               3     A    193      22.4
```

Here is the class I'm using to represent the data:

```
    public partial class Detail
    {
        public int ParticipantId { get; set; }
        public int TripId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public double? Weight { get; set; }
        public double? BodyFatPct { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my highly inefficient C# code to calculate best and worst for weight and body fat.

```
List<Detail> result = new List<Detail>();

var _result = result.GroupBy(x => new { x.ParticipantId, x.TripId });
foreach(var res in _result)
{
    var beforeHighWeight = res.Where(x => x.Type == "B").Max(x => x.Weight);
    var beforeLowWeight = res.Where(x => x.Type == "B").Min(x => x.Weight);
    var afterWeight = res.Where(x => x.Type == "A").Min(x => x.Weight);
    var beforeHighFat = res.Where(x => x.Type == "B").Max(x => x.BodyFatPct);
    var beforeLowFat = res.Where(x => x.Type == "B").Min(x => x.BodyFatPct);
    var afterFat = res.Where(x => x.Type == "A").Min(x => x.BodyFatPct);
    var BestWeightDiff = BeforeHighWeight - afterWeight;
    var WorstWeightDiff = BeforeLowWeight - afterWeight;
    var BestFatDiff = BeforeHighFat - afterFat;
    var WorstFatDiff = BeforeLowFat - afterFat;
}
```

In actuality, I have about 15 fields to calculate, not just two.  Is there a lambda function that does row-wise calculations on grouped data?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: One optimization you can do i.e. Filter list only once and then apply `.Min()` and `.Max()` on it.

Comment: Row-wise calculation can be performed using Aggregate. If you use Entity Framework you could thus stream the data and calculate the values without materializing all values in an array or list. How many entries are in your database and what kind of issues are you experiencing?

Comment: The code as posted doesn't really do anything.. It would be easier to help if we could see what you do with it

Comment: The database is under 10000 records, so pretty small @Clemens. I could easily create arrays but I am hoping to learn to be a better programmer as well as make the code more maintainable for the next person.

Answer (score 0):

Performance optimizations normally come with the cost of less maintainable code. So if performance is almost sufficient you should probably follow the hint as commented by Prasad Telkikar and avoid filtering `res` more than once with the same predicate, i.e. you should assign the filtered lists and work with them:

```
var resA = res.Where(x => x.Type == "A")
var resB = res.Where(x => x.Type == "B")
```

If performance is an issue and affords work, you can enumerate the list once and maybe stream the values from the database by using Aggregate. You could e.g. create a class that holds all the values you want to calculate and has a method to update the values given a new entry. You could e.g. create the classes

```
public class Statistic
{
    public int BeforeHighWeight { get; private set; }
    public int BeforeLowWeight { get; private set; }
    // Add the dimensions you are interested in 

    public Statistic(Detail detail)
    {
        // initialize with given Detail
    }
    public Statistic AddDetail(Detail detail)
    {
        // update Statistic with given Detail
        return this;
    }
}

public class Statistics
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<(int, int), Statistic>  _statistics = new ConcurrentDictionary<(int, int), Statistic>(); 

    public Statistics AddDetail(Detail detail)
    {
        _statistics.AddOrUpdate(
            (detail.ParticipantId, detail.TripId),
            key => new Statistic(detail),
            (key, statistic) => statistic.AddDetail(detail)
        );
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then you could aggregate your values like so:

```
var rand = new Random();
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000)
    .Select(i => new Detail {ParticipantId = i % 10000, TripId = rand.Next(100000) /*, ...*/})
    .Aggregate(
        new Statistics(),
        (statistics, detail) => statistics.AddDetail(detail)
    );
```